# DocuSign - How To Control Notification to Sender via API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the REST API to create a solution that will be used by multiple organizations.

Is there a way in the API to control who on the sender side receives the notifications?   By default all of the notification emails are being sent to the email I set up when I created my API account.  But I really need to be able to send those notifications to the person that actually sent the document.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static function sendForSignature($filename,  //The name of the file that will show up in the email
                                        $document_path, //The path to the file on the server
                                        $template, //The json template file for this document                                           
                                        $opportunity=null, //The opportunity if applicable
                                        $company_id=-1, //The company id if applicable
                                        $contact_id=-1) //The contact if applicable
{       
    $envelop_summary = null;
    $company = null;
    $contact = null;

    $sign_here_tabs=[];
    $full_name_tabs=[];
    $date_tabs=[];
    $text_tabs=[];
    $all_documents=[];

    $basePath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/doclib';
    $mappingPath = $basePath.'/mapping';

    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost(\Yii::$app->params['docusign_host']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", 
        "{\"Username\":\"" . \Yii::$app->params['docusign_username'] . 
        "\",\"Password\":\"" . \Yii::$app->params['docusign_password'] . 
        "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . \Yii::$app->params['docusign_integrator_key'] . "\"}");

    $apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $accountId = null;

    $organization = Organization::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->org_id]);
    $user = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->id]);

    if($opportunity !== null){
        $company = $opportunity->company;
        $contact = $opportunity->contact;
    }else{
        $company = Company::findOne(['company_id' => $company_id]);
        $contact = Contact::findOne(['contact_id' => $contact_id]);
    }

    try 
    {
        //*** STEP 1 - Login API
        $authenticationApi = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
        $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
        $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);

        if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
        {
            $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
            if(isset($loginInformation))
            {
                $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();

                $envelopeApi = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

                $index = 0;

                if(is_array($document_path)){

                    foreach($document_path as $d){

                        $pdf = new FPDI();
                        $page_count = $pdf->setSourceFile($d);

                        $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
                        $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($d)));
                        $document->setName($filename[$index]);
                        $document->setDocumentId($index+1);
                        $all_documents[]=$document;

                        $template_file = json_decode(file_get_contents($mappingPath .'/'. $template[$index]));

                        foreach($template_file as $t){
                            if($t->type == 'signHereTab'){
                                $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();

                                if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                    $signHere->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                    $signHere->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                    $signHere->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                    $signHere->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                                }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                    $signHere->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                    $signHere->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                                }

                                // $signHere->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                                $signHere->setDocumentId($index+1);
                                if($t->page == -1){
                                    $signHere->setPageNumber($page_count);
                                }else{
                                    $signHere->setPageNumber($t->page);
                                }
                                $signHere->setRecipientId("1");

                                $sign_here_tabs[]=$signHere;
                            }else if($t->type == 'fullNameTab'){
                                $fullName = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\FullName;
                                if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                    $fullName->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                    $fullName->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                    $fullName->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                    $fullName->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                                }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                    $fullName->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                    $fullName->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                                }

                                // $fullName->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                                $fullName->setDocumentId($index+1);
                                if($t->page == -1){
                                    $fullName->setPageNumber($page_count);
                                }else{
                                    $fullName->setPageNumber($t->page);
                                }
                                $fullName->setRecipientId(1);

                                $full_name_tabs[]=$fullName;
                            }else if($t->type == 'textTab'){
                                $text = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text;
                                if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                    $text->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                    $text->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                    $text->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                    $text->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                                }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                    $text->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                    $text->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                                }

                                if(isset($t->label))
                                    $text->setTabLabel($t->label);
                                // $text->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                                $text->setDocumentId($index+1);
                                if($t->page == -1){
                                    $text->setPageNumber($page_count);
                                }else{
                                    $text->setPageNumber($t->page);
                                }
                                $text->setRecipientId("1");

                                $text_tabs[]=$text;

                            }else if($t->type == 'dateTab'){

                                $date = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Date;

                                if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                    $date->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                    $date->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                    $date->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                    $date->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                                }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                    $date->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                    $date->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                                }

                                // $date->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                                $date->setDocumentId($index+1);
                                if($t->page == -1){
                                    $date->setPageNumber($page_count);
                                }else{
                                    $date->setPageNumber($t->page);
                                }
                                $date->setRecipientId(1);

                                $date_tabs[] = $date;
                            }
                        }

                        $index++;
                    }

                }else{
                    // Add a document to the envelope
                    $document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
                    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($document_path)));
                    $document->setName($filename);
                    $document->setDocumentId("1");
                    $all_documents[] = $document;

                    $pdf = new FPDI();
                    $page_count = $pdf->setSourceFile($document_path);

                    $template_file = json_decode(file_get_contents($mappingPath .'/'. $template));

                    foreach($template_file as $t){
                        if($t->type == 'signHereTab'){
                            $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();

                            if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                $signHere->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                $signHere->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                $signHere->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                $signHere->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                            }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                $signHere->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                $signHere->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                            }

                            // $signHere->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                            $signHere->setDocumentId("1");
                            if($t->page == -1){
                                $signHere->setPageNumber($page_count);
                            }else{
                                $signHere->setPageNumber($t->page);
                            }
                            $signHere->setRecipientId("1");

                            $sign_here_tabs[]=$signHere;
                        }else if($t->type == 'fullNameTab'){
                            $fullName = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\FullName;
                            if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                $fullName->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                $fullName->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                $fullName->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                $fullName->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                            }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                $fullName->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                $fullName->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                            }

                            // $fullName->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                            $fullName->setDocumentId(1);
                            if($t->page == -1){
                                $fullName->setPageNumber($page_count);
                            }else{
                                $fullName->setPageNumber($t->page);
                            }
                            $fullName->setRecipientId(1);

                            $full_name_tabs[]=$fullName;
                        }else if($t->type == 'textTab'){
                            $text = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text;
                            if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                $text->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                $text->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                $text->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                $text->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                            }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                $text->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                $text->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                            }

                            if(isset($t->label))
                                $text->setTabLabel($t->label);
                            // $text->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                            $text->setDocumentId("1");
                            if($t->page == -1){
                                $text->setPageNumber($page_count);
                            }else{
                                $text->setPageNumber($t->page);
                            }
                            $text->setRecipientId("1");

                            $text_tabs[]=$text;

                        }else if($t->type == 'dateTab'){

                            $date = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Date;

                            if(isset($t->anchorString)){
                                $date->setAnchorString($t->anchorString);
                                $date->setAnchorXOffset($t->anchorXOffset);
                                $date->setAnchorYOffset($t->anchorYOffset);
                                $date->setAnchorUnits($t->anchorUnits);
                            }else if(isset($t->xPosition)){
                                $date->setXPosition($t->xPosition);
                                $date->setYPosition($t->yPosition);
                            }

                            // $date->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent($t->anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent);
                            $date->setDocumentId(1);
                            if($t->page == -1){
                                $date->setPageNumber($page_count);
                            }else{
                                $date->setPageNumber($t->page);
                            }
                            $date->setRecipientId(1);

                            $date_tabs[] = $date;
                        }
                    }               
                }

                $tabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();

                if(count($sign_here_tabs) > 0)
                    $tabs->SetSignHereTabs($sign_here_tabs);
                if(count($full_name_tabs) > 0)
                    $tabs->setFullNameTabs($full_name_tabs);
                if(count($text_tabs) > 0)
                    $tabs->setTextTabs($text_tabs);
                if(count($date_tabs) > 0)
                    $tabs->setDateTabs($date_tabs);

                $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
                $signer->setEmail(trim($contact->email));
                if(!is_null($contact))
                    $signer->setName($contact->first_name.' '.$contact->last_name);

                $signer->setRecipientId("1");                                                   
                $signer->setTabs($tabs);

                $emailNotification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEmailNotification();
                $emailNotification->setEmailSubject('Please sign these document(s).');
                $signer->setEmailNotification($emailNotification);

                // Add a recipient to sign the document
                $recipients = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
                $recipients->setSigners(array($signer));

                $envelope_events = [
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("delivered"),
                    (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("completed"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("declined"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("voided"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent())->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode("sent")
                ];

                $recipient_events = [
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Sent"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Delivered"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Completed"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("Declined"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("AuthenticationFailed"),
                    // (new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEvent())->setRecipientEventStatusCode("AutoResponded")
                ];

                $event_notification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EventNotification();
                $event_notification->setUrl(\Yii::$app->params['docusign_callback_url']);
                $event_notification->setLoggingEnabled("true");
                $event_notification->setRequireAcknowledgment("false");
                $event_notification->setUseSoapInterface("false");
                $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateWithSoap("false");
                $event_notification->setSignMessageWithX509Cert("false");
                $event_notification->setIncludeDocuments("true");
                $event_notification->setIncludeEnvelopeVoidReason("true");
                $event_notification->setIncludeTimeZone("true");
                $event_notification->setIncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField("true");
                $event_notification->setIncludeDocumentFields("true");
                $event_notification->setIncludeCertificateOfCompletion("false");
                $event_notification->setEnvelopeEvents($envelope_events);
                // $event_notification->setRecipientEvents($recipient_events);

                $email_settings = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EmailSettings();
                $email_settings->setReplyEmailAddressOverride($user->email);
                $email_settings->setReplyEmailNameOverride($user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name);

                $envelop_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
                $envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Document(s) from: ".$user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name.' '.$organization->name);
                $envelop_definition->setEventNotification($event_notification);
                $envelop_definition->setEmailSettings($email_settings);

                // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
                $status = 'sent';
                $envelop_definition->setStatus($status);
                $envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
                $envelop_definition->setDocuments($all_documents);

                $envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, null);

                foreach($all_documents as $d){
                    $sd = new SignedDocument;
                    if($opportunity !== null)
                        $sd->opportunity_id = $opportunity->opportunity_id;
                    $sd->company_id = ($company == null) ? -1 : $company->company_id;
                    $sd->contact_id = ($contact == null) ? -1 : $contact->contact_id;
                    $sd->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->id;
                    $sd->signature_id = $envelop_summary->getEnvelopeId();
                    $sd->save();
                }

                return 201;             
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $ex)
    {           
        Yii::error("Exception: " . $ex->getMessage().' '.$ex->getResponseBody(),'Signature');
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which authentication mechanism are you using? Can you post some of your envelope creation code.

Comment: Hi @CodingDawg just added the complete set of code that sends out the docs for signature.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials that are specified in the Auth Header will be used to determine the sender account. In your example `$app->params['docusign_username']` will receive the emails for the sender as that's the person who is sending the document.

If you are creating an App that will be used by multiple organizations then [Legacy Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html#legacy-header-authentication) is not the correct approach.

You should be using  the [oAuth2](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) flow for your use case.

> **User Application**
>
> A user application is a client that authenticates every end user with DocuSign. These applications are typically web services, mobile applications, or desktop programs that authenticate individual users on the DocuSign platform. Once authenticated, users give consent for the application to display, send, or sign envelopes from their account. For user applications the OAuth2 auth flows are recommended.
>
> **Service Integration**
>
> A service integration is a service that integrates directly with a DocuSign account. This kind of integration is typically reserved for backend services that authenticate on the DocuSign platform, without the involvement of an end user. For example, a backend application could be integrated into a line of business application to automatically send new member sign-ups. For service integrations the custom X-DocuSign-Authentication header is recommended.

Comment: Hi @CodingDawg thanks for this information.  So can I continue to use the PHP SDK with oAuth or will I have to code directly to the REST Api?

Comment: The PHP sdk supports the Docusign oAuth api. See [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Api/AuthenticationApi.php#L305-L378) .. Also see more information [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client#user-applications-that-use-oauth-authentication)